# Styling foreach values with CSS without JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I've been curious if it is possible to move each value to right only with CSS with logic something like this:
  `<div ng-show="c.reviewId==item.id" style="margin-left:" . {{$index}}*10 . "px"">`

the output for example could be:

`1.something
   2.something
      3.something`

or must you use javascript/angular for this?

Comment: The sample `<div>` you posted already involves Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with CSS Less:

```
.loop(@n; @i : 1) when (@i =< @n)
{
  div:nth-of-type(@{i}) {
    margin-left: @i*10px 
  }

  .loop(@n; (@i + 1));
}

.loop(6);
```

The generated code will be this:

```
div:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
div:nth-of-type(3) {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
div:nth-of-type(4) {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
div:nth-of-type(5) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
div:nth-of-type(6) {
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

http://www.lesscss.de/

Answer (score -1):

It's doable with css only, in your iteration, just add padding-left with index*5 (for example)

```
 "<div style='padding-left:" + (index * 5).ToString() + "px'>"+index.ToString()+". hello</div>"
```

This will look the same you need

```
        <div style="padding-left: 0px">0. hello</div>
        <div style="padding-left: 5px">1. hello</div>
        <div style="padding-left: 10px">2. hello</div>
        <div style="padding-left: 15px">3. hello</div>
        <div style="padding-left: 20px">4. hello</div>
        <div style="padding-left: 25px">5. hello</div>
        <div style="padding-left: 30px">6. hello</div>
        <div style="padding-left: 35px">7. hello</div>
        <div style="padding-left: 40px">8. hello</div>
        <div style="padding-left: 45px">9. hello</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using JavaScript when the poster asked for a Pure CSS Solution